# Biased manager in IT industry

Tags: software-industry, united-states, manager, tech-industry, discrimination

My boyfriend who works in a US IT industry has a manager who is very biased towards certain country. He gangs up with them and gives them higher merit increase (he asked his colleague and he said the number). Reserves projects for them and tries to show them significantly higher than what they are.

There is the concept of discrimination towards a certain nationality which is illegal. But is being bias towards a certain nationality illegal? How to deal with it?

Comment: This needs country info

Comment: What proof does your boyfriend have that the merit increases and projects are unearned? That's going to matter a lot for the answer to, *How to deal with it?*. Also, what does "gangs up with them" mean? Are you saying that there's bullying happening or is this just about pay and assignments?

Comment: @BSMP, the problem with discrimination is it's difficult to prove. Normally there is no "hard proof". What would it be? An email in which the person states "nationality/ ethnicity A is better than all the others"? How probable is it that someone would write something like that? And even if they had, how probable is it the email would ever get known widely? And even if it got known widely, the argument could be: "no other nationality showed as much engagement/ skills on the project as nationality A, so my judgement was correct". In most cases, decisions and statements is everything there is

Comment: It's a US based company. And he asked the colleague and realized he got higher increase.

Comment: If your boyfriend feels like he's being discriminated against because of his nationality, the only option he has is to talk to HR about the favoritism and maybe an employment lawyer.  This is well beyond the scope of stack exchange to be able to resolve.

Comment: @JRodge01 probably should be lawyer *first* and then HR.

Comment: @TinaJ - you asked, *How to deal with it?* - what is your boyfriend's desired outcome or goal? What has he already tried? Raise aside, does he have any recordkeeping of specific incidents, or does he just feel that there's a problem?

Comment: @BigMadAndy What I was trying to get at is does the OP's BF have anything to go to HR  with. Are his coworkers messing up their work in some way? Is stuff going late or going out wrong? Are they the only ones getting certain information that should be shared with the entire team? "Coworker A shouldn't have gotten Big Project after messing up Medium Project" is different from "I think I'm a better employee than Coworker A". He might be right about the discrimination even without proof but it changes what he can/should do about it.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is as old as humankind, sad to say. It's notoriously hard for somebody to challenge it successfully, even when company rules or laws prohibit it.

That's partly because it's hard to prove harm. But it's mostly because people get upset and combative when they're called out about this kind of subtle discrimination.

Accusing people of racism in any form rarely persuades them to change.

If it's egregious a person can ask for a confidential meeting with HR or an executive. In the meeting they can ask for advice about how to be recognized for good work, and how to get better assignments.

It it sinks to the level of workplace harassment, a formal complaint may be appropriate. Read the company's anti-harassment policy carefully before making a complaint.

It may be best to be patient, and to let this boss know, repeatedly, that the person wants more challenging work. And, if possible, finding another job will be a good way to get out from under this cloud.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately this happens more or less everywhere.